# Can't get access from outside to the web server in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, springframework

I have a Linux instance in Amazon EC2. There is I deployed 2 Docker containers. One with Mysql, another one with Spring Boot. Container with Spring Boot has a TomCat server. I created a new Security group in EC2:

Inbound:

```
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 0.0.0.0/0
```

I can access to this TomCat server from Linux:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/client
```

But I can't get access from the Internet :

```
http://xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/client
```

Comment: Is Tomcat configured to only listen on localhost? That would give the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I didn't configure Tomcat to receive requests only from the localhost. As I understood this parameter server.address in the application.properties  file has 0.0.0.0 value by default. It means that TomCat can get requests from any PC by default. I didn't change this parameter. Also I checked my application in my local network and I can get access to it from other PC.